# add a columns to a pandas dataframe that enumerates the rows having the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add to the dataframe df a column that enumerates the rows having the same index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1','b1'],['a2','b2'],['a3','b3'],['a4','b4']],columns=['a','b'],index=[9,9,12,14])

df
Out[13]: 
     a   b
9   a1  b1
9   a2  b2
12  a3  b3
14  a4  b4
```

In practice I would like to add a columns 'day' so that

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,'a1','b1'],[2,'a2','b2'],[1,'a3','b3'],[1,'a4','b4']],columns=['day','a',''],index=[9,9,12,14])

df
Out[15]: 
    day   a    
9     1  a1  b1
9     2  a2  b2
12    1  a3  b3
14    1  a4  b4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and if need new column as first add [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df['day'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
     a   b  day
9   a1  b1    1
9   a2  b2    2
12  a3  b3    1
14  a4  b4    1
```

---

```
df.insert(0, 'day', df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1)
print (df)
    day   a   b
9     1  a1  b1
9     2  a2  b2
12    1  a3  b3
14    1  a4  b4
```